Proof of a double inequality by induction
Prove that for every n from the natural numbers:
$\frac{n}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n - 1} \leq n$
I worked all the way up to $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n}+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$
of the first inequality, but I don't know how to go on from here. I noticed that there are $2^n$ terms on the right side, so the size depends on $n$ which is why I don't know how to proceed. I tried proving this by induction, but I didn't get anywhere.
